# Change Attribute to all buttons with Console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a facebook page and i want to delete all my posts but in creator studio doesn't have an option to check all buttons and i have to click on each button to select the posts that i want to delete.

So i thought to do it with Javascript through console.

There is a div with id mediaManagerContentTable inside this div there are some divs and isnide these all divs there are the buttons bellow:

```
<button aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Select Row" class="_1gcq _29c- _1gco _5e9w" role="checkbox" type="button" style="border-color: rgb(190, 194, 201); background-color: transparent;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="_3w08 accessible_elem monochrome img sp_U6sh7kVs9gH_1_5x sx_b953f5" alt="" style="left: -2px; top: -2px;"></i></button>
```

When i am pressing a button the data attribute aria-checked="false" changes to aria-checked="true"

So i tried the code bellow but nothing happened.

```
var dataElems = document.querySelectorAll("[aria-disabled]")
for (var i=0;i<dataElems.length;i++) { 
    dataElems[i].setAttribute("aria-checked", "true");
}
```

Any suggestion please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what happens if you ```console.log(dataElems.length)```? Does it have a value?

Comment: if i use this: var x = document.getElementById("mediaManagerContentTable").querySelectorAll("[aria-disabled]");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  x[i].setAttribute("aria-checked", "true");
  x[i].click;
}

it changes the data atrtribute but the buttons remains unchecked.. so i need also a click function for all buttons